# Loss of precision: Parallel 2D FFT using 1D FFTW and MPI calls

Tags: mpi, fftw

I am trying to match the result of doing a 2D FFT using the already implemented calls in FFTW and my own version of 2D FFT via 1D FFTw calls and mpi communication. 
So, resuming, I've followed the theory:

```
1 - FFT in y dimension
2 - transpose the matrix
3 - MPI_Alltoall communication
4-  FFT in x dimension
5-  transpose back
6 - MPI_Alltoall communication
```

I've tried with a small number of processors (8- 12) and it seems to work fine. Correctness has been carried out using RMS between the 2D FFTW call and my own result. However, as I increase the number of cores and size of the matrix, it seems that I am loosing precision, ie. RMS fails because the error is larger than expected (I set the error to 1.0e-10):

- Given a matrix of 512x512 and considering RMS of tolerance of 1.0e-6:
  "**ERROR: Position 1 0 expected im-part 10936907150.600960 and got 10936907150.600958**"
- Given a matrix of 2048x2048 and considering RMS of tolerance of 1.0e-6:
  "**ERROR:Position 1 0 expected real part -4294967296.000107 and got -4294967295.999999**"

Why would I lose precision if all I am using are double types?

Comment: You should check the relative error for your tolerance. You are 2.509104e-12 % I think that's correct...

Comment: Floating-point arithmetic is non-associative. Small differences due to different order of evaluation of expressions are to be expected. Also it appears that you have set an absolute error threshold instead of a relative one.

Comment: What would be a reasonable relative error to consider as tolerance?